Random complete systems crash and freeze. I have tried replacing some hardware with no results, what else should i check?
On Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (Kernel 6.8), since I started using it, random system crashes occur. It doesn't matter what I'm doing or how long the PC has been on, at some point everything crashes, the mouse no longer moves, any keystroke combination doesn't respond, the audio crashes, and I can't access the PC in SSH. Complete crash. On Windows it does not happen, has never happened and gives no BSOD. I had the same problem also in the past with different versions of Ubuntu and Kernel (end even in PopOs) and never managed to solve it.
Hardware:

CPU: Ryzen 5 1600X
GPU: Nvidia 1050Ti / Radeon RX 6800
Motherboard: Asrock AB350 Pro4

Suspected GNOME
I tried using KDE Plasma instead of GNOME but the problem persists.
Suspected GPU
I tried booting the system without a video card and, connecting in SSH, it does not crash. I thought it might be the GPU's fault, so I installed a new Radeon 6800 video card but the problem persists. I don't think it's an Nvidia video card problem.
SSD Suspect
Starting Ubuntu live from USB Stick gives the same problem. SMART data from the SSD shows no problems.
RAM Suspect
I tried one at a time the two 8GB RAM sticks (GSkill F4-3200C16D-16GTZSK) the system crashes with both sticks. Windows, on the other hand, gives no problems and a MemTest86 reports no errors. I doubt it is a RAM hardware problem.
Trying with a stick from another computer (Crucial RAM 8GB DDR4 3200MHz) does not crash.
In all tests the BIOS was up to date and XMP disabled. What else could I try to figure out the cause of the problem?

You've not yet told us what OS/release you're using, as the GNOME & KDE Plasma desktops run on the base Ubuntu system, and we don't yet know what base Ubuntu release you're using. For some hardware, switching kernel stack can solve issues (esp. on newer/older hardware), but again that's based on release details (unrelated to GUI on top of base system)

@guiverc I am running Ubuntu 24.04 LTS - Kernel 6.8 (fresh install). But i had the same problem also in the past with different versions (end even in PopOs) and never managed to solve it.

I had similar bad experiences repeatedly in the past, so much so that it drove me away from Ubuntu/Xubuntu for several years. Since then however, I am free from such frustrations. The most significant thing I had changed, was that I bought a computer with ECC (Error Correction Code) memory and a corresponding/compatible processor. Or maybe it's just a coincidence. If it would turn out that this correlation is indeed important, that would be a sad day for Ubuntu; it is supposed to be a valid OS for those with low-spec hardware.

@Levente I am currently running a memtest just to be 100% that the RAM is ok, after that i will try a new Ryzen CPU from the 5000 serie for the sake of understanding by exclusion what are the problematic components. Just for pure curiosity, what OS you migrated to?

That's not very relevant :) But for the sake of completeness, I had gone back to Windows in those years.

I was hoping for the name of a more stable distro to try, cannot let windows win this game :(

Maybe look around in these threads too: https://askubuntu.com/q/1264859, https://askubuntu.com/q/1114612, https://askubuntu.com/q/1316623

The problem seems to be kernel 6.8 or later or the Mesa drivers (maybe vulkan).

I have the same problem as you and tested this issue on 2 different Intel 13-generation systems.
At first, I thought it was from Ubuntu, so I installed PopOS (the problem got worseو PopOS kernel is 6.9)
Then I thought it was from gnome extensions and replaced them (but it didn't fix the problem)
Then I installed KDE and noticed the problem persists!
I even noticed the same problem in the live version of Ubuntu and it froze a few times!
I tested both Wayland and x11 and the problem was not solved.

I did not see this problem in Zorin OS because it uses kernel 6.5 (I checked) or older mesa (I did not check).
So, I deleted the mesa drivers from Ubuntu and the system became stable, but it does not have proper graphics power.
I'm still trying to pin down the exact problem.

The problem is with kernel 6.8, believe me, I thought I lost my Lenovo laptop until I installed previous LTS Ubuntu with kernel 5 and now the laptop is working again. My laptop just completely froze up and overheated, crazy stuff.
